# Eager loading in ASP.NET MVC 3 (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have a simple data structure

- Employee
- Employee has List
- Education has University, Department
- Department and University has Name as string (I mean Dept. and Univ. are also entity)

My question is, how can I eagerly load specific Employee's education list and each education's university and department information in Entity Framework.

In ASP.NET MVC tutorials there is a query like:

```
var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
    .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
    .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
    .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);
```

But my include takes only string parameter (with **using System.Linq**)

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is't not in System.Linq, but in System.Data.Entity (so using System.Data.Entity) and exists in EF 4.1, but I must admit I don't know in which version it appeared.

Comment: Thank you! I updated to Entity Framework 4.3. **using.System.Data.Entity** worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

That snippet is for a new version of EF I thin. What 4.x version are you using?

You should be able to use the name(s) of the Navigation properties:

```
viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
    .Include("OfficeAssignment")
    .Include("Courses.Department")   // not so sure about this one
    .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);
```